# Select Date range in JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jaxb, single-page-application

I wan to send XML with Date to return XML response. I tried this:

**XML Request:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<reconcile>
  <start_date>2018-04-08</start_date>
  <end_date>2018-11-08</end_date>
  <page>1</page>
</reconcile>
```

**JAXB:**

```
    @XmlElement(name = "start_date")
    public Date start_date;
    @XmlElement(name = "end_date")
    public Date end_date;
    @XmlElement(name = "page")
    public String page;
```

import java.util.Date;

```
        Date start_date, Date end_date,
        String hql = "select e from " + PaymentTransactions.class.getName() + " e where e.created_at >= ? and e.created_at <= ? and e.merchant_id = ? and e.terminal_id = ?";
        Query query = entityManager.createQuery(hql).setParameter(0, start_date).setParameter(1, end_date).setParameter(2, merchant.getId()).setParameter(3, terminal.getId());
        List<PaymentTransactions> paymentTransactions = (List<PaymentTransactions>) query.getResultList();
        return paymentTransactions;
```

For table column type I use in MariaDB DATE type.

But when I send request nothing happens. 
Probably I need to convert the data before I send SQL query? Can you propose some solution?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think query parameter indexing starts with 1, not 0. Try incrementing the index in all `setParameter` calls.

Comment: Code looks good so far. Try to narrow down your problem with testing you condition step for step. First only with terminal condition, then date condtion and so on. At least some data should be returned.

Comment: @Shadov query parameters start from 1 when Hibernate is configured using `META-INF/persistence.xml` and from 0 when using `hibernate.cfg.xml`